# EWS (Exchange Web Services) - Add inline attachment to appointment

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I try to add an inline attachment to an appointment through web services for exchange 2010. I followed the steps described in this article (even though it describes email attachments), and it does not work: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh532564(v=exchg.80).aspx .
The attachment IS added to the appointment, but I do not get it to show in the body; I always get an empty space.

This is my code just copying an .jpg attachment from one appointment to another one:

```
// load the first attachment as stream
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
FileAttachment fileAttachment = (FileAttachment)appointment.Attachments[0];
fileAttachment.Load(stream);

// create new appointment
Appointment newAppointment = new Appointment(service);
string body = string.Format(@"<html>
                 <head>
                 </head>
                 <body>
                    <img width=100 height=100 id=""1"" src=""cid:{0}"">
                 </body>
                 </html>", "test.jpg");
newAppointment.Body = new MessageBody(BodyType.HTML, body);

// add the attachment to the appointment
byte[] bytes = stream.ToArray();
newAppointment.Attachments.AddFileAttachment("test.jpg", bytes);
newAppointment.Attachments[0].IsInline = true;
newAppointment.Attachments[0].ContentId = "test.jpg";

// save the appointment
FolderId folderId_Calendar = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, emailAddress);
newAppointment.Save(folderId_Calendar, SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone);
```

To clarify: I tried the method on email messages, and that works. Just appointments do not.

Comment: My discussion about this in the Microsoft forums: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/36a2cdce-9ec6-4e63-9252-e5fce9ccff9c/ews-exchange-web-services-add-inline-attachment-to-appointment?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment#76f963d6-a730-4d73-b93a-4cb9ba9443d6

Comment: Is it solved now ? Yes, how

Comment: No, it's not. Look at the discussion on Social MSDN I mentioned before. There seem to be restrictions when using HTML. Unfortunately I am not working on that project anymore, so there will be no updates on the issue in that regard.

Comment: anyway thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

According to this example you should set HasAttachments property too.

http://www.independentsoft.de/exchangewebservices/tutorial/createinlineattachment.html

Comment: Thank you, but the example you're referencing does not contain 'HasAttachments'. I tried to set it, but it is read only, as well. Also, the example handles email messages; I tried inline attachments with email messages, and that works. Just appointments make difficulties.